# Cant' connect to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, go

I have a MySQL server on CentOS 7 and I want to try connecting a program written in Go to that database server. For the database server (MySQL) is work correctly and I tried to make one database and table.

```
+-----+------------+
| no  | nama       |
+-----+------------+
| 001 | Example    |
+-----+------------+

MySQL username: golang
MySQL password: cobadatabase
```

**CentOS 7 (MySQL Server) Machine's IP: `192.168.102.175:3306` (Default Port)**
**and My laptop's IP: `192.168.102.170`
**. So, Database server exist on different machine (remotely).**

Here is my Go code:

```
func main() {
    /* Ini konekin database-nya dulu */
    app_database, err := sql.Open("mysql", "golang:cobadatabase@tcp(192.168.102.175:3360)/example")

    /* Nah klo ini Error Handling */
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)  // informasi log jika koneksi database gagal
    }
    defer app_database.Close() // Close koneksi jika benar-benar gagal
    /* End of Error Handling Connection */

    var (
        no string
        nama string
    )

    baris, err := app_database.Query("SELECT * FROM example_table")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer baris.Close()

    for baris.Next() {
        err := baris.Scan(&no, &nama)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(no, nama)
    }
    err = baris.Err()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

When I run my program, it fails with this error:

> dial tcp 192.168.102.175:3360 connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond.

Comment: use **3306** instead of 3360 as port

Comment: Yeay... It is working. Thanks a lot for your help. Very kind of you

Comment: Note that port 3306 is the standard one for MySQL DB instances, so you might as well not specify it at all -- the driver should use that automatically. That is, you only need to specify the port when you want to override the default value -- for the case when your server listens on a non-standard port (or, say, a connection to it is "port-forwarded" using SSH or another tunneling solution).

Comment: And another suggestion: next time, please specify the name of the package you're using to work with MySQL: neither Go itself nor its standard library contain any database drivers, and there exist several implementations of MySQL driver for Go. So if you question wasn't that simple, we'd need to know which package you were using to try help you.